# Plotting count of unique values in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset with that form :

```
>>> df
         my_timestamp    disease  month
0 2016-01-01 15:00:00       2      jan
0 2016-01-01 11:00:00       1      jan
1 2016-01-02 15:00:00       3      jan  
2 2016-01-03 15:00:00       4      jan  
3 2016-01-04 15:00:00       2      jan
```

I wont to count the number of unique apparition by month, by values, then plot the count of every value by month.

> > > df
> > > values    count
> > > jan       2         3
> > > jan       2         3

How can I plot it ? In one plot with month on x axis, one line for every values, and their count on y

Comment: can you try this: `df.groupby('month')['disease']nunique().plot()`

Comment: @remc please accept one of the answers as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to get that data into barplot.
I created a month column. Then :

```
for v in df.disease.unique():
   diseases = df_cut[df_cut['disease']==v].groupby('month_num')['disease'].count()
   x = diseases.index
   y = diseases.values
   plt.bar(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot by month, then you also need to plot by year if multiple years. You can use `dt.strftime` when using `.groupby` to group by year and month.

Given the following slightly altered dataset to include more months:

```
       my_timestamp  disease    month
2016-01-01 15:00:00       2      jan
2016-02-01 11:00:00       1      feb
2017-01-02 15:00:00       3      jan  
2017-01-02 15:00:00       4      jan  
2016-01-04 15:00:00       2      jan
```

You can run the following

```
df['my_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['my_timestamp'])
df.groupby(df['my_timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))['disease'].nunique().plot()
```

[image]

Comment: It works but it return the number of unique values, and not the occurence of values.

Comment: @remc what about using `.count()` instead of `.nunique()`? You can also use `.size()`. Does that work?

Comment: yep ! Cf my response